# Button in Discord Bot (c#) - D#

Tags: c#, button, discord, bots, message

I am a novice programmer and I am trying to create a bot. I acted on the lessons at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ooZ0_IkPVk, and used D# to develop
I have a question - how to add buttons to a post via embed?
Here's my code for example

```
var joinGames = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
            {
                ImageUrl = "bla bla,
                Title = "bla bla bla",
                Color = DiscordColor.Blue,
                Description = ":bla bla bla \n" +
                              "bla bla"
            };
```

This is where I want to add buttons, how do I do that? Are they supposed to be displayed as a message?

```
await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: joinGames).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

But my button doesn't connect

```
var myButton = new DiscordButtonComponent(ButtonStyle.Primary, "my_custom_id", "This is a button!");
```

Very please advice or solutions, maybe there are books and articles that I should read to understand how best to attach what? Sorry for the mistakes in the text, my native language is not English

Comment: await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(builder: testButton).ConfigureAwait(false);
This was done by replacing two words, I don't know why I didn't think of it before

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to add component to it

```
joinGames.AddComponents(myButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DiscordMessageBuilder` you can attach buttons to your Embed

```
var messageBuilder = new DiscordMessageBuilder();
var embedBuilder = new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
{
    Title = "Post title",
    Color = DiscordColor.Blue,
    Description = "Here is post description",
};
messageBuilder.AddEmbed(embedBuilder);
var button = new DiscordButtonComponent(ButtonStyle.Primary, "my_button_id", "This is a button!");
messageBuilder.AddComponents(button);
```